# How to refresh/update DataGridView with new data from CSV file?

Tags: c#, csv, windows-forms-designer

I am currently making a Windows form in Visual Studio 2017.
I have the DataGridView displaying the data from the CSV correctly. 
The problem is when the user inputs some data and saves it and then looks at the DataGridView the data doesn't contain the new data until the program is closed and opened again.

So when the user presses the button `Save as Preset` the csv is updated however the data in the DataGridView is not.

[image]

I have searched the web and can't find any solutions and have tried the usual `PresetView.Refresh();` and `PresetView.Update();` but is seems that that doesn't fix many people problems either.

Button Code:

```
public void ButtonProperties()
{
    SaveCustomPreset.Click += new EventHandler(SaveCustomPreset_Click);
}
```

Writing to CSV code:

```
private void DisplayPresetData(string filePath)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string[] csv_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    string[] data_col = null;
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string text_line in csv_data)
    {
        data_col = text_line.Split(',');
        if(x == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() -1; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
            }
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(data_col);
        }
    }
    PresetView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Button click code:

```
private void SaveCustomPreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("../../PresetData.csv", true);
    txt.WriteLine(CustomPresetName.Text + "," + CustomX.Text + "," + CustomY.Text + "," + CustomZ.Text + "," + Foam.Text);
    txt.Close();
    PresetView.Refresh();
    PresetView.Update();
}
```

Comment: this might become obvious after I ask you this question, but where in your code are you calling that private method `DisplayPresetData` ?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Up in a public class. It is just calling the method `public CrateConfigurator() { DisplayPresetData("../../PresetData.csv"); }`

Comment: In button click event add data to DataTable. Also remove Refresh and Update calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sample, you're creating a new instance of a `DataTable` type, and then assigning it to your control as a datasource.

thus, your control's datasource is that object instance that was created in that scope.

```
private void DisplayPresetData(string filePath)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string[] csv_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    string[] data_col = null;
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string text_line in csv_data)
    {
        data_col = text_line.Split(',');
        if(x == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() -1; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
            }
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(data_col);
        }
    }
    PresetView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Refreshing the control is not going to automatically call this method.

You can do a couple things to handle this:

---

You can cast the DataSource (which is actually a `DataTable` type) to `DataTable` and Add data to it in the `SaveCustomPreset` EventHandler method scope.

```
private void SaveCustomPreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var columns = new [] 
    {
        CustomPresetName.Text, 
        CustomX.Text, 
        CustomY.Text, 
        CustomZ.Text, 
        Foam.Text
    };

    var line = string.Join(",", columns);
    using (TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("../../PresetData.csv", true))
    {
        txt.WriteLine(line);
    }

    var dt = (DataTable)PresetView.DataSource;
    foreach(var item in columns)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item)
    }
}
```

or, you can call to the `DisplayPresetData(string filePath)` method in that event handler (or a similar method that reads data off the file and assigns it to PresetView.DataSource)

The benefit of the second implementation is that you can account for modifications on the csv from scenarios outside of your writing to it.

The benefit of the first implementation is performance. (that is, you avoid the stream file reading, buffering, and looping operations in that method, and instead, you would do incremental Adds.)

Comment: It works! I used your last solution by adding the method to the Button Event. Thank you!